# Pass two values from user input to a function and get result

Tags: python

I have been given instructions to "write a program that asks the user to enter values for mass and velocity, and then calls the *kinetic_energy* function to get the object's kinetic energy."

I have written code that is logically correct but I am wondering if I have the syntax backwards then what is described in the instructions. I believe my *main* function is calculating the result and simply passing it to the *kinetic_energy* function. I believe the instructions are asking for it to be done in the reverse order. If my assumption is correct how would I rewrite it to comply with the instructions?

```
#Gets the inputs from the user for mass and velocity
def main():
    mass = int(input('Please enter the objects mass in kilograms: '))
    velocity = int(input('Please enter the objects velocity in meters per second: '))

#Calculates the kinetic energy
    kinetic_energy(ke = .5 * mass * velocity ** 2)

#Calculates the kinetic energy
def kinetic_energy(ke):
    print ('The amount of kenetic energy is ',format(ke,',.2f'),sep='')

main()
```

Comment: I don't understand why you think this is wrong. You already did "call a function" (two of them you defined yourself), so why is that your question title?

Comment: What exactly were the instructions? as written, you're calculating the kinetic energy inside the input to your function...

Comment: Was the definition of the `kinetic_energy` function given for you, or did you write it yourself?

Comment: you have the ide, just move the calculate line into the ke call,  and pass in mass and velocity and return the ke result.  then print that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you write functions that do "work".

So if you have a `kinetic_energy` function, you wnat that function to do some more work than just printing.

So, it'd be more appropriate to rewrite your stuff as:

```
#Gets the inputs from the user for mass and velocity
def main():
    mass = int(input('Please enter the objects mass in kilograms: '))
    velocity = int(input('Please enter the objects velocity in meters per second: '))

#Calculates the kinetic energy
    kinetic_energy(mass, velocity)

#Calculates the kinetic energy
def kinetic_energy(mass, velocity):
    ke = .5 * mass * velocity ** 2
    print ('The amount of kenetic energy is ',format(ke,',.2f'),sep='')

main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You define `kinetic_energy` as a function that takes two arguments, mass and velocity, then returns the computed value:

```
def kinetic_energy(m, v):
    return .5 * m * v ** 2
```

Then you call the function from `main`:

```
def main():
    mass = int(input('Mass in kilograms: '))
    velocity = int(input('Velocity in m/s: '))
    ke = kinetic_energy(mass, velocity)
    print('Kinetic energy is {.2f}'.format(ke))

main()
```

Comment: Isn't that a matter of opinion that the function returns the result and the two parameters are given?

Comment: Perhaps, but it's good design to separate computation from output. You may not always want to immediately output the computed kinetic energy, or you may want a different format.